# I'm facing a problem with selecting in jtable

Tags: java

I'm trying to select a row from table reading user database and change it depending on which selected row I have chosen in the table and change the fields and combo-boxes as selected row in the table.

```
public class Users extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JLabel username,password,type,department;
JButton update,delete;
JTextField user_f;JPasswordField password_f;
JComboBox ctype,cdepartment;
JTable user_table;
JScrollPane scroll;
String[] ltype={"ST","TA","PR"};
String[] ldepartment={"CS","IT","IS"};
String Data[][];
String Header[]={"USERNAME","PASSWORD","TYPE","DEPARTMENT"};
ArrayList<domain.user> array=users_db.get_users();

public Users(){
    //show_Users();
}
public void show_Users(){
    Data=new String[array.size()][4];
    for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
       Data[i][0]=array.get(i).getUsername();
       Data[i][1]=array.get(i).getPassword();
       Data[i][2]=array.get(i).getType();
       Data[i][3]=array.get(i).getDepartment();}
    //Defining  Table
    user_table=new JTable(Data,Header);
    scroll=new JScrollPane(user_table);scroll.setBounds(0,0,500,375);
    ///Windows Components
    username=new JLabel("Username");password=new JLabel("Password");
    user_f=new JTextField();password_f=new JPasswordField();
    update=new JButton("Update");delete=new JButton("Delete");
    type=new JLabel("Type");ctype=new JComboBox(ltype);
    department=new JLabel("Department");cdepartment=new JComboBox(ldepartment);
    username.setBounds(15, 350, 90, 80);user_f.setBounds(15,400,200,30);
    password.setBounds(220, 350, 90, 80);password_f.setBounds(220,400,200,30);
    type.setBounds(15, 400, 90, 80);ctype.setBounds(15,450,200,30);
    department.setBounds(220, 400, 90, 80);cdepartment.setBounds(220,450,200,30);
    update.setBounds(120, 520, 90, 30);delete.setBounds(230, 520, 90, 30);

    //Adding Actions to button
    //update.addActionListener(this);delete.addActionListener(this);
    //Creating Object of mouse listener to the table
    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)user_table.getModel();
    int SRN=user_table.getSelectedRow();
    user_f.setText(model.getValueAt(SRN,0).toString());
    password_f.setText(model.getValueAt(SRN, 1).toString());
    ctype.setSelectedItem(model.getValueAt(SRN, 2).toString());
    cdepartment.setSelectedItem(model.getValueAt(SRN, 3).toString());            

    //End creating
    //Adding Components+ Window Settings
    add(scroll);
    add(username);add(user_f);
    add(password);add(password_f);
    add(type);add(ctype);add(department);add(cdepartment);
    add(update);add(delete);
    setSize(500,650);
    setLayout(null);
    setVisible(true);   
}
 }
```

And here is a screenshot from the frame to clarify things:

[image: JTable frame]

Comment: You want to read about java naming conventions. You are violating them quite a bit, which makes things hard to read ... and I think you dont have a [mcve] here. No main method?

Comment: Aside: are you building a computer system where people's passwords are stored/available in plaintext? That is generally to be discouraged. Look up "password hashing".

Comment: No, I have a main method actually but i'm just building this project for college

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this code can help. You have to attach listener on row selection like this:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
        public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {
            // do some actions here, for example
            // print first column value from selected row
            System.out.println(table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have one more question to clear my doubts about event `MouseAdapter` and `MouseListener` and `ListSelectionListener` 
Why `ListSelectionEvent` works with combo-boxes and `MouseListenEvent` does not?

Comment: When i click on a row,it add type and  department in the combo-box but doesnt change the selection of combo-box as it is specified in the selected row